# Load device drivers into kernel

Tags: operating-system, kernel, computer-science

In Linux Operating System, device drivers are also loaded into kernel along with operating system. Sometime these drivers get crashed due to some circumstances and operating system become not responding or restarts. To avoid these situations, **first approach is to load these drivers into the core kernel.** **Secondly, these drivers can be loaded into kernel as a separate process.**

To avoid such problem which method should be used and why?
1st or 2nd?

Comment: Use/Write drivers that are stable? :D

Answer (score 1):

In Linux kernel there is no such thing like "separate process" for the driver. Drivers operate in the same address space as the kernel core and share threads with the kernel core.

Situation when crash in a device driver may crash entire OS is **unavoidable** in the vanilla Linux kernel.

Comment: Yes, as it is with most, (all?), OS.